# Is there is way I can solve this question in nlogn complexity

Tags: java, algorithm

You are given a sequence of N integers A denoted by A[1] , A[2]…..A[N].
Each integer in the sequence has a value associated with it W[1],W[2]…. W[N].
You have to select a subsequence of given array A such that all the elements in A are in strictly increasing order and sum of values of elements in this selected subsequence is maximum. You have to print this maximum value.

Sample Input

```
2  
4  
1 2 3 4  
100 200 300 400  
3  
4 2 3  
100 30 20
```

Sample Output

```
1000   
100
```

I tried to solve this problem using dynamic programming but the time complexity of my code is n^2 so i want to reduce its complexity to nlogn can you help me?

Here is my implementation:

```
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = scn.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            int n = scn.nextInt();
            int a[] = new int[n];
            long val[] = new long[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = scn.nextInt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                val[i] = scn.nextLong();
            }

            long dp[] = new long[n];
            Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            dp[0] = val[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (a[j] < a[i]) {
                        dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i], dp[j] + val[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            long ans = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for (long v : dp) {
                ans = Math.max(v, ans);
            }
            sb.append(ans + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

I am getting TLE because of contraints

Constraints
1 <= T <= 5 1 <= N <= 200000 1 <= a[i] <= 10^9, where i ∈ [1..N] 1 <= w[i] <= 10^9, where i ∈ [1..N]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate once, and maintain a `TreeMap` of the sum of W values for A values less than or equal to the given A, as seen at the time you iterated over the A value.

For a new `A`, call the [`lowerEntry(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerEntry-K-) method for the sum of W's below that new A.

Remember the largest sum, and return that.

Single iteration is *O(n)*, and `TreeMap` use is *O(log n)*, so solution is *O(n log n)*<sup>*</sup>.

```
static int sumIncreasing(int[] a, int[] w) {
    int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sums = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> lowerSum = sums.lowerEntry(a[i]);
        int sum = (lowerSum != null ? lowerSum.getValue() + w[i] : w[i]);
        sums.put(a[i], sum);
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e; (e = sums.higherEntry(a[i])) != null && e.getValue() <= sum; )
            sums.remove(e.getKey());
        if (sum > maxSum)
            maxSum = sum;
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

<sup>**) The inner `for` loop is O(log n) (amortized, worst case), so it doesn't affect overall complexity.*</sup>

*Test*

```
System.out.println(sumIncreasing(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}, new int[] {100, 200, 300, 400}));
System.out.println(sumIncreasing(new int[] {4, 2, 3}, new int[] {100, 30, 20}));
```

*Output*

```
1000
100
```

Comment: if we are not allowed to use hashmap and treemap then can we do it with binary search or not.

Comment: @KashishSingh [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a "Red-Black tree", and a [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) is a kind of self-balancing binary search tree, so yeah, you can use a homegrown one if you want, but why would a challenge (and the question reads like one) limit what native APIs you can use?

Comment: @ruakh Yeah, you're right, but it's actually _O(log n)_ because `higherEntry()` is. Amortized, worst case is actually `3 * log n` for the inner loop (`higherEntry + remove + higherEntry`), added to the `2 * log n` from the other code (`lowerEntry + put`), for a total of `5 * log n`, but that's still _O(log n)_ for one iteration of the outer loop body. I was just trying to keep it simple and say that the inner loop doesn't change anything. Guess I over-simplified.